# Unable to plot `errorbar` work with `datetime` datatype in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, errorbar

I would like to plot `errorbar` with `datetime` on x-axis

```
x = datetime(['21-Aug-2019'; '22-Aug-2019'; '23-Aug-2019']);
y = [100; 110; 130];
figure
plot(x,y, '.')
hold on
errorbar(x, y, 20)
```

The final line produces this error-
    `Error using errorbar (line 76)`
    `Input arguments must be numeric or objects which can be converted to double.`
Even the following produces error

`errorbar(datenum(x), y, 20*ones(size(y)))`

I am using R2016b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errorbar` does not support `datetime` object. You can use `datenum` and `datetick`.
datenum will convert your string vector containing your date into a double vector. Now that x is a double vector it can be used in `errorbar`.

Finally convert your x label into human readable date format with `datetick`.

```
x = datenum(['21-Aug-2019'; '22-Aug-2019'; '23-Aug-2019']);
y = [100; 110; 130];

figure
hold on
plot(x,y, '.')
errorbar(x, y, [20;20;20])

datetick('x','dd-mmm-YYYY')
```